I can't paste in Flutter
when I use TextField,I want to copy and paste.
but I can't do that
when I copy. then click long  TextField
it just have cut、copy and select All. no paste
Flutter SDK version: 2.5.1
(I know it's old. but I can't update)
I try to use ClipboardData,
I can copy , ClipboardData has data.
but when I paste, text = "".
example:
ClipboardData.text = "abc"
when paste
ClipboardData.text = ""
why, how to do this?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Ensure that your app has the necessary permissions to access the clipboard. You might need to request these permissions, especially on iOS.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clipboard/clipboard.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Clipboard Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter text here',
                ),
                onSubmitted: (String value) {
                  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: value));
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('Text copied to clipboard')),
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ClipboardData data = Clipboard.getData();
                  if (data != null && data.text != null) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text('Pasted text: ${data.text}')),
                    );
                  } else {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text('No text in clipboard')),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Paste'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Try this code, this may resolve it.

yes,  in my app.  first ClipboardData.setData, then ClipboardData.getData,  but ClipboardData.text = "",  this is my question.

then in your phone its not copying, check that it copied or not

I sure it copied, I have images, but they said do not upload Images.

I breakpoint in Clipboard.dart.  it copied

You are pasting images?

You didn't mentioned in question that you are pasting the images

I mean ，I upload Images in this question. In proof of my Clipboard it copied.

I'm sure my phone has copied, I have an image to prove that I did. But I cannot upload this image to show it to you.
